# How to check when a React component has updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that regularly gets updated and I'd like to build a utility function outside of this component, where it needs to updates its internal state when the component has updated.

For example:

```
class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 1 };
  }
}

class Utility {
  constructor(componentInstance) {
    this.internalNum = // computedInstance's internal counter state (how?)
    // and when the component has updated, I'd like to change the internalNum (how?)
  }
}
```

I know this can be achieved if I were to pass the `Utility` function into the `Sample` function and have `Sample` updated `Utility` based on React's life cycle methods, but I don't want to introduce a that sort of dependency into `Sample`.

Perhaps there is a better design pattern here ... or if this is fine, how would it work?

Comment: What would happen if you render multiple instances of `Sample`?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps there is a better design pattern here

Basically you have to hook into the fact that `Sample` calls `setState` with a new value. Such a thing is best exposed by `Sample` (as a callback or an event).

Alternatively you can move the state out of `Sample` into a global place e.g. using `redux`.

## More

https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @basarat that you should implement redux just because you should always implement redux (because it rocks). Anyway, it is posible to make a workaround in this scenario using static properties.

```
var _counter;

class Sample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 1 };
    _counter = 1;
  }

  updateCounter() {
    var newCounter = this.state.counter + 1

    this.setState({ counter: newCounter });
    _counter = newCounter;
  }

  static get counter() { return _counter; }
}

class Utility {
  constructor(componentInstance) {
    this.internalNum = Sample.counter;
  }
}
```